# How to solve this issue i got only in Moto g?

Tags: android, image, gallery

[image]
 i am try to choose image form gallery and crop the image.i tested more than 5 devices i got only problem with Moto g.how to solve this problem?i am using TabGroupActivity

my code

parent activity

public class TabGroup1Activity extends TabGroupActivity{

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    startChildActivity("OptionsActivity", new Intent(this,ProfileActivity.class));
}


protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
        Intent intent) throws ClassCastException {
   if (requestCode == 1) {
       Family activity = (Family)getLocalActivityManager().getCurrentActivity();
       activity.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    }
    else if (requestCode == 2) {
        Home activity = (Home)getLocalActivityManager().getCurrentActivity();
        activity.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        }
```

child activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
            android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);`enter code here`

    getParent().startActivityForResult(
            Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), SELECT_PICTURE);`




public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {`switch (requestCode) {
    case SELECT_PICTURE:
        try {
            mImageCaptureUri = data.getData();
            doCrop();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        break;
}}
```

`

Comment: It's very Difficult to solved device specific issue....

Comment: What exactly the problem is? Explain or share logcat

Comment: You didn't attach the photo (but your markup says that you tried). Please, check it, as the photo can help us a lot!

Comment: pls check. i updated my logcat.

Comment: me getting toeast message like "Editing isn't support for this message" in cropping image from gallery how to fix this

Answer (score 0):

Note that your activity may be recreated on posting result from gallery or camera.Please save your current state of the activity in onSavedInstatnceStae() and restore the same if your activity is recreated. Refer [Here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html) for more info

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
outState.putString("ImageUri", imageUri);
 }

protected void restoreSavedInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
imageUri = savedInstanceState.getString("ImageUri");
}

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
if(savedInstanceState != null)
  {
    restoreSavedInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
   }
 }
```

Comment: i am using TabGroupActivity.how to save current state in tabgroup.

Comment: onSavedInstanceState() not available for TabGroupActivity?

Comment: After ACTION_PICK selected the gallery view came on the top of the screen. Now the android OS can kill the your activity. If its get killed then your onActivityResult() method will be called after recreating your activity means your onCreate() method will be called again before onActivityResult() Called. So if you have any variables  it will be initialised new. that means your values inside the variables before calling gallery will be lost.

Comment: To avoid losting of variables values you could save the values inside the activity bundle like i saved the imageuri in bundle with the key "ImageUri"(OnSavedInstanceState()). if oncreate() called again my saved value will come inside the savedInstanceState Bundle. From that bundle i can restore the value again.

Comment: me getting toeast message like "Editing isn't support for this message" in cropping image from gallery how to fix this